# In Angular (v6), socket.io 'on' method's (socket.on()) callback function is not getting called for 'message' type

Tags: angular, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am working on a Demo WebSocket app. The tech stack consist of following:

Frontend:

- Angular(v6)
- Socket.io

Web Server:

- Nginx

Backend:

- Flask
- Flask-Socketio
- uWSGI

I am able to establish a WebSocket Connection and also able to send/receive message from my web app. I can see the message being sent/received in the`Chrome -> Network -> WS` section as shown below.

[image]

So, I am sending `Hey!!` and receiving back `'message', 'my message'`. This part looks alright to me. The **issue** is that now I want to take this `incoming message` and display it in my app. However, I am **not** able to store this message or `console.log()` the incoming response from server as the `socketio.on('message', callback())` callback method is not getting fired, which essentially has the logic to process the incoming message as shown below:

> This is the partial code block from `app.service.ts` that is **not** working. Complete code snippet is pasted below.

```
 public onMessage(): Observable<any> {
return new Observable<any>(observer => {
  console.log('hereeee');// This console happens
  // This below method is not firing
  this.socket.on('message', (data: any) => {
    console.log('Received a message from websocket service');
    observer.next(data);
  });
});
```

}

I am pasting complete server and client code snippets below.

Server:

```
@socketio.on('message', namespace='/websocket_test')
def msg(msg):
    socketio.emit('message', 'my message', room=request.sid)
```

Client:

I am using Angular + RxJS to define my `socket.io` service methods. Also, I have added `comments` in snippets below to indicate what is working and what is not.

> app.service.ts

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client';

export enum Event {
  CONNECT = 'connect',
  DISCONNECT = 'disconnect'
}
     @Injectable()
        export class AppService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

      private socket;

      public initSocket(): void {
        this.socket = socketIo('/websocket_test');
      }

      // This method is used to send message to backend
      public sendMe(message: any): void {
        this.socket.emit('message', {data: message});
      }

      public onMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<any>(observer => {
          console.log('hereeee'); // This console happens
          // This below method is not firing
          this.socket.on('message', (data: any) => {
            console.log('Received a message from websocket service');
            observer.next(data);
          });
        });
      }

      // This gets called on connect and disconnect event.
      public onEvent(event: Event): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<Event>(observer => {
          this.socket.on(event, () => observer.next());
        });
      }

    }
```

> app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  messages = [];
  isConnected: boolean;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initIoConnection();
  }

  private initIoConnection(): void {
    this.appService.initSocket();

    // This happens
    this.appService.onEvent(Event.CONNECT)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.isConnected = true;
        console.log('connected');
      });

    this.appService.onMessage()
      .subscribe((message: any) => {
        // not getting called
        console.log('Message', message);
        this.messages.push(message);
        // console.log(this.messages);
      });

    this.appService.onEvent(Event.DISCONNECT)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.isConnected = false;
        console.log('disconnected');
      });
  }

  public myMessage(message: string): void {
    if (!message) {
      return;
    }

    this.appService.sendMe({
      from: this.user,
      content: message
    });
    this.messageContent = null;
  }
}

export enum Event {
  CONNECT = 'connect',
  DISCONNECT = 'disconnect'
}
```

I have tried few things to figure out the issue but with no luck. If anyone is familiar with this issue or has any idea on what I am doing wrong, Please comment here. Any input will be appreciated. Let me know if any additional details is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking myself and going through several examples online, I figured out the problem with my application. It was on the backend.

If you notice the `server` side snippet that I have shared in the question above, I am defining the `socketio` event like this:

```
from server.main import socketio

@socketio.on('message', namespace='/websocket_test')
def msg(msg):
    socketio.emit('message', 'my message', room=request.sid)
```

So, I am doing an `import` of `socketio` from `main/__init__.py` file, where I am declared my `flask` app and also initialized `socketio` instance. And I am using that instance to emit events to client as `socketio.emit('message', 'my message', room=request.sid)`. This here **(the way I emit was the issue)**. The correct way is to import `emit` in this file and and use that as shown below:

```
from server.main import socketio
from flask_socketio import emit

@socketio.on('message', namespace='/websocket_test')
def msg(msg):
    emit('message', 'my message', room=request.sid)
```

Let me know if anyone has any inputs here. I hope it will help anyone out there stuck on similar problem :)

Comment: The `emit()` function is context-aware. It will emit on the same namespace the incoming event came (`/websocket_test`). The `socket.emit()` function is a generic function that doesn't use context information, if you don't provide a namespace then it will emit on the default namespace instead of the namespace that you are using.

Comment: @Miguel - Thanks for the explaining the difference. Now, I understand why it was failing for my `/websocket_test` namespace.